# Интеграция PDF в WinForm

Tags: pdf

мне нужно открыть PDF файл прямо на форме, желательно библиотекой из NuGet.
Есть ли пример, как это можно сделать.
Просто открыть PDF файл на форме.
Adobe пожалуйста не предлагайте.

Comment: Вы можете использовать компонент GeckoWebBrowser. Как это сделать, описано здесь: https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-the-gecko-web-browser-in-a-c-winforms-project/. Только ваша строка для открытия pdf-файла в браузере будет примерно такой: geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("c:\\путь к файлу\\File.pdf")

Answer (score 0):

Для использования GeckoFX45 в Visual Studio Comunity 2019 выполните следующие шаги:

1. Создайте новое приложение Windows Forms, например, с именем GeckoExample.
2. В консольном менеджере пакетов NuGet: install-package geckofx45.
3. В каталоге назначения найдите папку: packages\geckofx45\45.0.34\lib\net45 с файлами Geckofx-Winforms.dll и Geckofx-Core.dll. Добавьте в решение ссылки на эти файлы.
4. Если geckoWebBrowser не появился в панели элементов, то открываем окно Toolbox/Choose Items, далее - кнопка Browse(Обзор) - указать на файл Geckofx-Winforms.dll (см.выше).
5. Добавить компонент geckoWebBrowser из Toolbox на форму.
6. В свойствах проекта укажите целевую платформу: x86.
7. Скачайте библиотечный файл xpcom.dll например, здесь: http://dlltop.ru/x/107-xpcom-dll и поместите его в папку c:\windows\system32 (если он там отсутствует).
8. Добавьте в проект следующий код:

```js
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;

namespace GeckoExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Xpcom.Initialize(@"c:\путь к пакету\packages\geckofx45\45.0.34\content\Firefox\");
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
            this.geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(@"c:\temp\File.pdf");
          //  this.geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сравнения, используем стандартный компонент Adobe PDF Reader. Для этого:

1. Открываем окно Toolbox/Choose Items, далее - вкладка Компоненты COM - отмечаем checkbox для Adobe PDF Reader - OK.
2. Добавим компонент Adobe PDF Reader из Toolbox на форму.
3. Добавьте в проект следующий код:

```js
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string filePath = "c:\\temp\\File.pdf";
    this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filePath);
    this.axAcroPDF1.src = filePath;
    this.axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
    this.axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
    this.axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
    this.axAcroPDF1.Show();
  }
```

Имеем тот же результат с меньшими затратами.